# Dynamically add to @Html.DropDownList that is already being populated by using ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

I have a `@Html.DropDownList` that I populate using a ViewBag within my controller. I am looking to see if it is possible to be able to have the dropdown load the values from the controller yet be able to add a new one if needed and then save it when saving the complete record.

My view contains

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaterialTypesID, "Material Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("MaterialTypesID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaterialTypesID)
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Controller -

```
 private void PopulateMaterialTypeList(object selectMaterialType = null)
    {
        string voidInd = "Y";
        var materialType = db.MaterialTypes
            .Where(x => x.VoidInd == voidInd)
            .OrderBy(x => x.MaterialType1);

        ViewBag.MaterialTypesID = new SelectList(materialType, "MaterialTypesID", "MaterialType1", selectMaterialType);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean dynamically add a new option value to `<select>` in the view?

Comment: Would that tie into my table and not a Select List with in my controller?

Comment: You can just have an 'Add' button in your view that opesn a popup to add the new `MaterialType`, and use ajax to save it, then append a new `<option>` to your `<select>`

Comment: Are you trying to add a blank option or an actual, usable value?

Comment: Actual usable value. I thought about adding an 'Add' button however then I would have to reload the page. Any data entry they entered in the other fields would be either lost or I would have to store them in a temp table and load them on reload of the page.

Comment: If you use ajax, you do not need to reload anything

Comment: How about just adding a value to the combo with JS? You would have to identify a new value on post back, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that using `MaterialTypesID.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Text","Value"));` would work. Haven't tested it, but I don't know what would stop you from doing that after you populate with data.

Comment: Would that be in the controller or the view?

Comment: The goal of what you're trying to attempt is 1) populate a dropdown using a viewbag and then 2) add values to the already existing dropdown? Am I correct in saying that? You have your controller above handling the initial populate, you could then call another controller action that would add more to it using the line that I wrote.

Comment: You are correct in stating my intention. Currently, the dropdown does not allow entry, it is read only.